# I could not remove items from the arraylist. How to remove items from the array list in android?

Tags: android

I could not remove items from the arraylist while using interface in android.

```
@Override
public void spinnerData(SpinnerData2 spinnerData) {

    spinnerDataList.add(spinnerData);
    /*int j = spinnerDataList.indexOf(spinnerData);
    int st= spinnerDataList.size();*/
    /*Toast.makeText(this, ""+st, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

}

@Override
public void spinnerDataRemove(SpinnerData2 spinnerData) {

    spinnerDataList.remove(spinnerData);

}
```

Comment: pls post more code

Comment: `i could not remove items from the arraylist` why? what stops you from doing that?

Comment: please share your error logCat

Answer (score 0):

You can use index to remove data

```
spinnerDataList.remove(index);
```

index means position of your item in arraylist starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mess while trying to remove certain indices or list objects

If you are passing a primitive index, then you will remove item at certain position; otherwise, you will remove object from the list that equals to the passed-in object

Example

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
list.add("four");
list.add("five");
Log.d("TAG", + list); // [one, two, three, four, five]
list.remove(1); // removes item at index 1 which is "two"
Log.d("TAG", + list); // [one, three, four, five]
list.remove("five"); // removes object that equals to "five"
Log.d("TAG", + list); // [one, three, four]
```